# Test if env variable is empty or does not exist

Tags: python

I've set the following env variables:

```
$ export a=''
$ export c='foo'
```

`b` does not exist.
I want a single python condition to return True on `a` and `b` and False on `c`

Comment: You can just use `os` : `'MY_ENV' in os.environ` will test whether it is defined.

Comment: Thanks, but then I'll need to have a second statement to test if the value is not empty.